# LINT1/NMI purple screen Dell R710 with Vmware

Tags: vmware, esxi

I have an Dell R710 server with Vmware. An it keeps crashing with the following purple screen. Can someone point me to the right direction? I tried different versions of vmware and the same (6.0, 6.5, 6.7).

[image: screenshot image]

Thank You.